# Use GROUP BY/ HAVING, but then expand the results

Tags: mysql, group-by, having

I am not sure if my title question makes sense.  But I have the query below.

```
SELECT mdn,
       cost_center, 
       sum(data_allowance) AS allowance, 
       sum(mib) AS 'sum_usage', 
       rate_plan 
FROM verizon 
GROUP by cost_center
HAVING SUM(mib) > SUM(data_allowance);
```

Which give me the data over lines that went over their allowance.  This is the information that I want, but there are multiple lines associated with each cost center. Although every line may not be over I still want to `SELECT` those lines.   On the other hand, there are lines that may be over their allowance, but as a total,  they did not go over their allowance and I do not want to display that information.

Hope this is clear and thank you in advance.

Comment: Do I get this right: You want to add some cost centers, that are not over their allowance and exlude some cost centers, that are over it?

Comment: Yes, but the ones I want to include are the ones that as a total `SUM(mib) > SUM(data_allowance)`  I want to exclude the ones that as a total are not over.  Does that make sense?

Comment: That is exactly what your code does now I think. You have a syntax error at AS 'sum_usage', that's all I can see.

Comment: There's no syntax error here. However, while MySQL forgives the omission, in general, any non-aggregated column included within a SELECT clause must also be included within the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: No there is no syntax error, the query works.  There are several different lines associated with each cost center.  Which led me to try  `GROUP BY cost_center, line` but that didn't give me the results.  Now I am thinking I need use a subquery to `WHERE cost_center IN ( ..`  I am going to try to work that for a little

Comment: is it really possible to write the column name in single quotes? Or is it a copy effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to get the detail associated with the cost centers?  If so, then use a `join`:

```
SELECT v.*
FROM verizon v JOIN
     (SELECT cost_center
      FROM verizon 
      GROUP BY cost_center
      HAVING SUM(mib) > SUM(data_allowance)
     ) vsum
     ON v.cost_center = vsum.cost_center;
```

If you want the summarized values as well, you can include that in the `vsum` subquery and select the summarized values.

Comment: Plus 1 for the additional suggestion.  That would be helpful as well